# Simple lattice proofs

Tags: proof-writing, order-theory, lattice-orders

Suppose that (X,≤) is a lattice and x,y ∈ X. Prove that: 
x ∧ ( x ∨ y ) = x

I'm having trouble understanding how these types of lattice proofs should be structured. I've looked at similar ones and found this approach:

Let a = x ∧ ( x ∨ y )
Then a ≤ x and a ≤ ( x ∨ y )

But, I'm not sure what "a" is exactly? I have a whole set of these types of proofs to do but I don't have an example to go off of, so if someone could walk me through this one, it would be super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a$ is just an abbreviation for $x\land(x\lor y)$ that they introduced so they don't have to keep writing that long expression.

The fact that $a\le x$ and $a\le (x\lor y)$ follows from the defintion of $\land$ as meaning the greatest lower bound (if it is a lower bound, it is less than both of them).

That $a\ge x$ follows from the fact that $x$ is less than or equal to both $x$ and $x\lor y,$ and thus it is a lower bound for them. And thus $a\ge x$ since $a$ is the greatest lower bound.

Comment: I've seen authors use the notation to distinguish between making definitions (such as the "let" example here) using $:=$ and asserting equality of expressions involving previously defined variables using $=$.  So, for example: Let $a := x \wedge (x \vee y)$.  Then $a \le x$, and so on ...  Therefore, by antisymmetry, $a = x$.

Comment: Could you explain the third paragraph a bit more? I assume x ≤ x (this seems obvious) and x ≤ x∨y (is this because x∨y is an upper bound for x and y?). You say x is a lower bound for x and x∨y, but so is a. x and a seem equivalent to me, so why is a the greatest lower bound? I'm confused at where the a≥x comes from. Thanks btw!

Comment: @sy89 The mission of the problem is to show that $x$ and $a$ are the same thing (that $x=a$). So since they are the same thing, it is indeed true that $a$ and $x$ are both the greatest lower bound of $x$ and $x\lor y.$ The difference is that $a$ is *defined* to be the greatest lower bound (since $a$ is just an abbreviation for $x\land (x\lor y)$), so you can use that fact from the outset. Thus we first show that $x$ is *a* lower bound (not necessarily the greatest), and then we know $a\ge x$ since $a$ is the greatest lower bound. (And your reasoning is right for showing $x$ is a lower bound).

Comment: @sy89. Thus we have $a\ge x.$ And in the second paragraph, I showed that $a\le x.$ Combining these two gives $x=a$ and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

Your first strategy could be to unwrap definitions, and for this problem no more is needed.

> **Join:**
>   $a\vee b$ is an element satisfying $a\vee b\leq a$, $a\vee b\leq b$, and if $z$ satisfies $z\leq a$ and $z\leq b$, then $z\leq a\vee b$

$\phantom{}$

> **Meet:** 
>   $a\wedge b$ is an element satisfying $a\wedge b\geq a$, $a\wedge b\geq b$, and if $z$ satisfies $z\geq a$ and $z\geq b$, then $z\geq a\wedge b$

$\phantom{}$

$x\vee y$ is an element such that $x\vee y\leq x$, $x\vee y\leq y$ and if $z\leq x$ and $z\leq y$, then $z\leq x\vee y$.

Now, just verity that $x$ satisfies the definition of $x\wedge (x\vee y)$.

You have that $x\geq x$, $x\geq (x\vee y)$, by definition of $x\vee y$ above,

If $z\geq x$ and $z\geq (x\vee y)$, then in particular $z\geq x$.